# interpolate values between sample years with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to get interpolated values for the metric shown below using Pandas time series.

**test.csv**

```
year,metric
2020,290.72
2025,221.763
2030,152.806
2035,154.016
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates={'Timestamp': ['year']},
                    index_col='Timestamp')
```

As far as I understand this gives me an time series with the January 1 of each year as the index. Now I need to fill in values for missing years (2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2026 etc)

Is there a way to do this with Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, interpolation only fills in values, where there are none. In my case above, what I had to do was to re-index so that the interval was 12 months.

```
# reindex with interval 12 months (M: month, S: beginning of the month)
df_reindexed = df.reindex(pd.date_range(start='20120101', end='20350101', freq='12MS'))

# method=linear works because the intervals are equally spaced out now
df_interpolated = df_reindexed.interpolate(method='linear')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a newer version of Pandas, your DataFrame object should have an interpolate method that can be used to fill in the gaps.

Comment: That was my hunch too. Using `method=time`. I couldn't figure out how to specify yearly intervals though.